# Broadcasting in Breeze CSCMatrix?

Tags: scala, sparse-matrix, scala-breeze

Is it possible to use broadcasting in Breeze CSCMatrix objects?
On a `DenseMatrix m`, broadcasting works like the following:

`sum(m(::, *)`

However, the same operation on a `CSCMatrix m` yields this error:

```
scala> sum(m(0 to m.rows - 1, *))
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for parameter canSlice:  breeze.linalg.support.CanSlice2[breeze.linalg.CSCMatrix[Int],scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive,breeze.linalg.*.type,Result]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slicing and broadcasting haven't been fleshed out for CSCMatrix yet, sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Is there any recommended alternative idiom for such operations? I would like to normalize a column of ones so that the sum of the column is 1, i.e. divide each value by the sum of the column.
Also, would you mind if I open an issue on that in spite that I cannot really contribute to it?

Comment: I think right now there's just not. Obviously there should be.